# Converting an image in 8-bit grayscale RAW image in java

Tags: java, image-processing

Please let me know how to convert a JPG/PNG/BMP image into a 8-bit grayscale RAW image in Java. Is it possible to obtain using ImageIO API?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert an image to 8-bit grayscale using [`ColorConvertOp`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorConvertOp.html) with a `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` as the `filter()` destination. Here's an [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/d4c436ab64d4ced4).

[RAW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) is actually a family of vendor-defined image formats, many of which can be read with [jrawio](http://jrawio.rawdarkroom.org/). Once converted, you might be able to write with [ExifTool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool).